# how to fix the "npm WARN config `_auth`, `_authToken`, `username` and `_password` must be scoped to a registry." issue

Tags: npm, .npmrc

Any time I use nom command I get this warning in the beginning:

```
npm WARN config `_auth`, `_authToken`, `username` and `_password` must be scoped to a registry. see `npm help npmrc` for more information.
npm WARN config `_auth`, `_authToken`, `username` and `_password` must be scoped to a registry. see `npm help npmrc` for more information.
```

I've checked my `.npmrc` file, but the file that opens with the `npm config edit` looks fine for me, as there should not be such a problem.

That's my `.npmrc` with stripped comments and replaced sensitive data (all the structure is correct):

```
@my_scope:registry=https://registryurl/npm/
//registryurl/npm/:_password="[secret]"
//registryurl/npm/:username=my.email@domain.com
//https://registryurl/npm/:_password=YOUR_BASE64_PASSWORD
//https://registryurl/npm/:always-auth=true
//https://registryurl/npm/:email=first.second@domain.com
//https://registryurl/npm/:username=first.second@domain.com
always-auth=true
email=my.email@anotherdomain.com
registry=//registryurl/npm/
```

What could possibly be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I have also encountered this warning every time I use npm commands after upgrading to NodeJS version 16, I was also wondering what was causing the warning.

What resolved the issue for me was deleting the keys mentioned in the warning, using this command:

```
npm config delete key _auth _authToken username _password
```

This deleted the old entries on my user's .npmrc (I'm using Windows 11 and this file is located inside `C:\Users\<your.user>\.npmrc`)

Since we're now using a `.npmrc` file within our git repository (unaffected by npm config) which uses the newer auth related config convention, this approach worked effectively for me.